# Image Processing With Windows IoT Core

Tags: rpi.gpio, sensor, windows-iot

I am a Newbie to Raspberry Pi Windows IoT core, I wanted to create a system to detect total number of Chairs/Tables present in a room for business, I researched a lot, I had a few sites stating that I have to use a PIR sensor(which I doubt it'll work as its mostly used for calculating distance let alone shapes). another concept is I interface a Camera to the Pi and take snapshots at each interval and make it detect shapes from the image(Less efficient). Anyone with a better idea? I need help Thanks!

Comment: It could be easily done on Raspbian with the help of OpenCV or any other packages such as  motion or something similar. I don't think it would be very difficult on Win 10 IoT as well. This could be the starting point. https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/WebCamSample.htm

Comment: @dastaan Thank you so much for the reply. I haven't worked a lot on raspbian either so sorry, the OpenCV or motion you are referring to, do they provide image processing? will I need to program them to detect a shape resembling a table?

Comment: If you want to detect a shape or something, I suggest you to use OpenCV and use template matching or using haar cascades although you will have to train haar cascades for table on your own or you can use your custom algorithm which works for application. Motion, as far as I know, use image subtraction to see if there's any motion in subsequent frames.

Comment: @dastaan Thank You for the help shall look into it and shall get back. :D